# How to restart mobile when ad show up in Unity Game?

Tags: android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mobile, ads

In my game the player can watch an ad to activate a skill with grants the player more coins. But when the button is pressed and the ad is supposed to start, the game restarts.

My game isn't published in the playstore, could this also cause this error?

thanks!

Comment: Add more explanation and part of the code you think is the issue origin.

Comment: What adsupplier are you using and show some code!

Comment: Ad provider: Unity Ads   Script is at https://answers.unity.com/questions/1577736/game-restarts-when-it-is-supposed-to-show-ads.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, version mismatch is the problem in my case. If you open an old project with a newer version of Unity, Unity ADS plugin might still be loaded from the previous project. Since newer releases come with the ad plugin built-in, this causes contradiction between them. Solution is remove the ad plugin (if exists), reimport the project and set up the ad services according to the documentation.

You can find it here: [Unity Ads Quick Start](https://unity3d.com/services/ads/quick-start-guide)